# Application settings binding best practices

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, windows-runtime, uwp

I've been struggling for a while now with how to best "interact" with settings on a binding level in a WinRT/UWP app. I've been looking for best practices regarding this, but I haven't found clear answers. What I've done so far in my apps is the following:

1. Define a BindableBase which implements INotifyPropertyChanged.
2. Create an AppSettings class which inherits from BindableBase and looks a bit like this:

   ```
   public class AppSettings : BindableBase
   {
       ApplicationDataContainer localSettings = ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings;

       public string MySetting
       {
           get
           {
               if (!localSettings.Values.ContainsKey("MySetting"))
                   localSettings.Values["MySetting"] = "Some default value";

               return localSettings.Values["MySetting"].ToString();
           }
           set
           {
               localSettings.Values["MySetting"] = value;
               RaisePropertyChanged();
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Define a ViewModel which has a an AppSettings property:

   ```
   public class SettingsViewModel
   {
       public AppSettings Settings { get; set; } = new AppSettings();
   }
   ```
4. Bind to the Settings property in the View:

   ```
   <TextBlock Text="{Binding Settings.MySetting, Mode=TwoWay}">
   ```

I've seen and used implementations in the past that had a settings service, but these applications didn't need the settings changes to go in effect immediately. So what I'm basically asking is: If changes to settings should go immediately into effect, is the above implementation a good way to bind to settings? If not, what do you recommend?

Comment: related: [Best practice zombies](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/142354/1228) Also, could use clarification by what you mean *to go in effect*. Do you mean saved immediately?  I know with WPF there is nothing that exists in the framework that does any of this for you.  You seem to already have something that should work (ish?). If it doesn't do what you need, change the code so that it does.

Comment: I think your implementation is fine and works how you want it to for your situation. If you need each setting to be applied immediately (instead of clicking a save button) then you'll have to assign the new value in the property set (as you have). Any subscribed listeners to changes in the property set will be triggered at that time.

Comment: @Will I'm not so much looking for a best practice but if there's something wrong with my implementation, because I feel like it's not very efficient performance-wise.

Comment: You feel?  Or you know?  Don't feel.  Get a tool (don't ask, I don't have) that can measure the performance and identify places where you can improve it.  All we can do is guess.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This seems fine in a general case. The only thing I'd change would be to only raise the notification if the data actually changes:

```
set
{
    if (MySetting != value)
    {
        localSettings.Values["MySetting"] = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

This will avoid raising notifications unnecessarily.
Depending on the frequency the values are read, you may want to keep your own in memory copy of the setting values (in a private field) instead of reading them from the container each time.

Comment: Storing the values in a private field and only changing the ApplicationData only if there's been changes to that might be a bit better performance-wise indeed. As for my implementation of RaisePropertyChanged, it already checks if a setting has changed if I remember correctly, but I'll check that to make sure.

Answer (score 5):

I was very inspired by this article so I came up with something a tad bit more elegant to avoid having to copy and paste the property name (key) so many times. I use the following:

```
public class SettingsViewModel : BindableBase
{
    public string MyProperty
    {
        get
        {
            return Get("MyProperty", "SomeDefaultValue");
        }
        set
        {
            Set("MyProperty", value);
        }
    }

    public T Get<T>(string PropertyName, T DefaultValue)
    {
        //If setting doesn't exist, create it.
        if (!App.Settings.ContainsKey(PropertyName))
            App.Settings[PropertyName] = DefaultValue;

        return (T)App.Settings[PropertyName];
    }

    public void Set<T>(string PropertyName, T Value)
    {
        //If setting doesn't exist or the value is different, create the setting or set new value, respectively.
        if (!App.Settings.ContainsKey(PropertyName) || !((T)App.Settings[PropertyName]).Equals(Value))
        {
            App.Settings[PropertyName] = Value;
            OnPropertyChanged(PropertyName);
        }
    }
}
```

Assuming your `App` class defines the following property:

```
public static IPropertySet Settings
{
    get
    {
        return Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values;
    }
}
```

The latter is more convenient than writing,

```
ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values
```

And can still be accessed globally.